# utop require package warning : cannot read directory /usr/lib/ocaml/METAS: No such file or directory

Tags: ocaml, utop

When I type `#require "` in `utop`, I get this message every time I type an additional character after `"`.

```
[WARNING] cannot read directory /usr/lib/ocaml/METAS: No such file or directory
```

Package importing doesn't seem to be working. I tried re-installing `utop` via `opam` but the error persists. Does anybody know what might be wrong?

Comment: did you do `eval $(opam env)`, and if you did, then what is the output of `opam env`?

Comment: Running `eval \`opam config env\`` fixed it. Is it recommended to run this manually all the time or should I add it to my `.bash_profile` or something?

Comment: Yep, add it and run it every time to be sure :)

Answer (score 0):

*One possible cause*, not the only cause, can be that you're missing the Ocaml libraries. On Debian you can install `ocaml-libs`.

Comment: not true, i had the same error, and after "apt-get install ocaml-libs" still get the same error.

Comment: It is true: it fixed it for me. I'm not saying it's the only possible cause.